# A confusing conditional probability puzzle

Tags: probability

I have been asked to work through this question on a homework, and am quite stuck.

Given three events A, B, and C such that P(A ∩ B ∩ C) =/= 0 and P(C|A ∩ B) = P(C|B),
show that P(A|B ∩ C) = P(A|B).

So far, I have played around with P(C|A ∩ B) = P(C|B)but this leads me to P(C (∩ A  ∩ B)) = P(C  ∩ B) and the same with P(A|B ∩ C) = P(A|B).

Does this mean that P(A ∩ B) = P(B)? Do you have a different perspective on this problem that could lead me to an answer?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(A|B\cap C)=\frac{P(B\cap C|A)P(A)}{P(B\cap C)}$$
by Bayes' rule
$$=\frac{P(C|B\cap A)P(B|A)P(A)}{P(C|B)P(B)}$$
by conditional probability definition
$$=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$
by the given condition
$$=P(A|B)$$
by Bayes' rule

Comment: I feel so silly to not have realized Bayes' Rule. Thank you. I think I've over studied this weekend and my brain was just done.

Comment: Yup! Most of these problems are fairly straightforward applications of Bayes' rule once you get the hang of it

Answer (score 0):

$P(C \mid A \cap B) = P(C \mid B)$ is equivalent to $\frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(A \cap B)} = \frac{P(B \cap C)}{P(B)}$, so if you prove this last equality is true, you have solved the problem.

$P(A \mid B \cap C) = P(A \mid B)$ is equivalent to $\frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(B \cap C)} = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$. This gives you an expression for $P(A \cap B \cap C)$; plug it into the earlier equation above and check if it holds.